# Is it a good learning rate for Adam method?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to estimate systolic blood pressure. I put PPG features (27) to the ANN. I got the result as below. Is it a good learning rate? If not, is it high or low? This is my result.

I set the learning rate for 0.000001. I think its still too high. It decreases too fast i think.

loss: 5.1285 - mse: 57.7257 - val_loss: 6.0154 - val_mse: 73.9671

```
# import data
data = pandas.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",")
data = data[["cp", "st", "dt", "sw10", "dw10", "sw10+dw10", "dw10/sw10", "sw25", "dw25",
             "sw25+dw25", "dw25/sw25", "sw33", "dw33", "sw33+dw33", "dw33/sw33", "sw50",
             "dw50", "sw50+dw50", "dw50/sw50", "sw66", "dw66", "sw66+dw66", "dw66/sw66",
             "sw75", "dw75", "sw75+dw75", "dw75/sw75", "sys"]]

# data description
described_data = data.describe()
print(described_data)
print(len(data))

# # histograms of input data (features)
# data.hist(figsize=(12, 10))
# plt.show()

# index and shuffle data
data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
data = data.reindex(numpy.random.permutation(data.index))

# x (parameters) and y (blood pressure) data
predict = "sys"
X = numpy.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = numpy.array(data[predict])

# Splitting the total data into subsets: 90% - training, 10% - testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)


def feature_normalize(X):   # standardization function
    mean = numpy.mean(X, axis=0)
    std = numpy.std(X, axis=0)
    return (X - mean) / std


# Features scaling
X_train_standardized = feature_normalize(X_train)
X_test_standardized = feature_normalize(X_test)

# Build the ANN model
model = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
model.add(Dense(25, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=27))
# Adding the second hidden layer
model.add(Dense(units=15, activation='sigmoid'))
# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.summary()
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000001)

# Compiling the model
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])


#Early stopping to prevent overfitting
monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=10, verbose=1, mode='auto',
                        restore_best_weights=True)
# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
history = model.fit(X_train_standardized, y_train, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2, epochs=1000, batch_size=5)
```

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Fv4.jpg)
[loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtywe.png)

[prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnhUz.jpg)

Comment: To be honest, saying whether your learning rate is too high or not without knowing what your data looks like is a difficult thing... It does seem from your graph that your loss is very quickly falling (with these hyperparameters you quite surely don't need so many epochs), but this could be due to many things. You could be overfitting, your data could be presenting characteristics (it could be linearly separable) which would mean using feed-forward neural network probably isn't the best way to do prediction, etc.

Comment: Is it possible that you add details on what you are trying to achieve and how you do it for now?

Comment: i put some information

Comment: Have you tried validating your actual learning results with some test data? Are the results performing as expected?

Comment: yep they look as i expected, but there are some samples that increase my RMSE

Answer (score 3):

**Your learning rate is not being used** because you don't compile the model with your `optimizer` instance.

```
# Compiling the model
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
```

Should be:

```
# Compiling the model
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'])
```

**Concerning the question itself:** As The Half-Blood Prince mentioned, it's hard to say without knowing your data set. Furthermore, the landscape of the data itself is important. I would really suggest the following though:

- Consider putting your features within the range (0,1), which can be done with [sklearn.preprocess.MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html).
- Instead of the graduate approach of deciding on your hyper-parameters, **optimize them** according to your validation data, and test the final result on a hold-out test set. [Hyper-parameter optimization is so easy with skopt](https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameter-optimization-in-python-part-1-scikit-optimize-754e485d24fe).